# «Докупи» у значенні «заразом»/«заодно»/«by the way»

Tags: from-english, значення-слів, from-russian

У російській мові є слово «заодно», наприклад:

> Она зашла в магазин за картошкой и заодно купила капусту.

В українській мові, згідно з тлумачним «Словником української мови» ([в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaodno), [у 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31083&page=1013)), теж є слово «заодно́» з тим же значенням:

> – Ось на тобі два пенси: зайди до магазину й спитай коробку “Альбо”. Та заодно спитай, чи багато його купують (М. Йогансен);
>
> Завтра мене викликають в район, то заодно вже підкину і вас до станції (Олесь Гончар).

Також є в українській мові й слово «заразо́м» ([СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/zarazom), [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=31959&page=1035)) з тим же значенням:

> — Вип'ємо, товариші, за Січ, щоб довго вона стояла на погибель бусурманам .. Та вже заразом вип'ємо і за нашу власну славу, щоб не забув нас мир (О. Довженко).
>   *<sub>(Тут не в значенні «всі спільно вип'ємо», а в значенні «за Січ і за власну славу підняти одну чарку».)</sub>*

Але проблема в тому, що мені в такому випадку підсвідомо хочеться поставити слово «доку́пи», мабуть, хтось із мого оточення вже використовував його в такому значенні:

> Вона пішла в крамницю за харчами й докупи придбала нові  виделки.

Але ані в [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/dokupy), ані в [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=23609&page=797) я цього значення слова "докупи" не бачу. Не бачу я цього слова й у перекладах іншомовних слів у міжмовних словниках:

> Заодно — *(сразу)* заразо́м, за одни́м за́ходом <…> ([Ізюмов](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&scope=rusb&dicts=2)).
>
> Купил заодно и краски — купив заразом (за одним разом, за одним заходом) і фарби ([Вирган і Пилипинська](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&scope=rusb&dicts=7)).
>
> Заодно́ — <…> 2) *(за один раз)* за одни́м хо́дом, за одни́м за́ходом, за одни́м ра́зом, ура́з. [Піду́ в книга́рню, та за одни́м хо́дом (за́ходом) і в бібліоте́ку зайду́. Неха́й уже за одни́м ра́зом і ва́ші сорочки́ поперу́ з свої́ми. Віта́ймо дитя́тко і враз його́ ма́тку (Чуб. III)] ([Кримський і Єфремов](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE&scope=rusb&dicts=1)).
>
> way: <…> by the ~ — між іншим <…> ([Кочерга та Мейнарович](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=by+the+way&dicts=4), [Мейнарович та Кратко](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=by+the+way&dicts=2)).

Тож чи є хоч якесь обґрунтування для застосування слова «доку́пи» в цьому значенні хоча б у розмовному стилі чи в частині випадків?

Answer (score 1):

Зазначу, що питання справді складне.

Згідно до [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/dokupy), як ви й самі зазначили, дане слово не має значення "заодно" чи "заразом". Також перевіримо [Словник синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B8) і бачимо такі слова: разом, укупі, поспіль, посполу, купно, спільно, **заодно**, гуртом, заєдно тощо. Як бачимо, слово "заодно" може бути синонімом до "докупи" однак у значенні: "Здійснюючи щось одностайно":

> "Старших зневажає ваша Леся. На мене сьогодні насипалася, ображала,
>   базікою назвала. **Заодно** (можна замінити на "докупи") з Греком Генкою
>   (А. Хижняк)"

Як бачимо у цьому контексті слово "заодно" має зовсім інше значення. Серед синонімів до слова "[заразом](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53399/265207.html)" також не бачимо "докупи".

Крім того, я перевірив [Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53396/357313.html), і в жодному з поданих там фразеологізмів "докупи" не вживається у значенні "заодно".

На [офіційному сайті української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/d/dokupi/27-1-0-3242) до слова "докупи" подаються такі синоніми: до гурту, в одне ціле, воєдино; разом.

Як бачите, згідно до всіх наведених вище джерел основним значення слова "докупи" є "В одно місце; разом". Крім того я переглядав шукав слово "докупи" в книгах Гугл і в жодній з тих, що мені зустрілися, не вдалося знайти слова "докупи" у значенні "заодно".

Отож, робимо висновки, що "заодно" та "докупи" можуть бути синонімами лише у заченні "разом". На жаль, знайти фактів, які б могли підтвердити ваші припущення, мені не вдалося, однак, як я зазначив на початку - питання справді складне і тому не можна із 100% впевненістю сказати, що дане слово не можна вживати у значенні "заодно", однак гадаю, що все ж найкраще для цього використовувати слово "заразом", "водночас", "воднораз" (згідно до [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53399/265207.html) слово "заодно" - запозичене).